# Using Node.js to SSH and then telnet from within the SSH session

Tags: ssh, javascript, node.js

At my job, we frequently need to SSH into a linux server and from within the session, telnet to another modem/router and execute various commands.

My question is, would it be possible to do this using [`simple-ssh`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh) or [`ssh2shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2shell) Node.js packages. I can login to the SSH session and execute commands without issue but there doesn't seem to be a way to login to the telnet session and maintain the connection.

Literally telnet.

Comment: When you say “Telnet” do you literally mean `telnet` or you mean another SSH session?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just run the `telnet` command the same way you issue any other command to the SSH session.

Then your question becomes the same as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts/7021653

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/833729)

Comment: Unless he can run the telnet command, in which case this IS the answer. The only limitation is availability of the telnet command on the system he has SSHed in to.